# Did Mom have a chicken farm?

Tags: futurama

In 'Bender's Game' we see that Mom had been farming dark matter from the Nibblonians. To get the dark matter she force-fed chickens to the Nibblonians.  If it was their only food it would take millions of chickens to feed the thousands of Nibblonians. Did Mom have a chicken farm to keep up with all these chickens?

Comment: [Meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2017/1109)